# I want flag icon to call service on clicking flag icon not both the services i am trying to use event.stoppropagation()

Tags: javascript, angular

I have tried this in order to updateFlag mail but when i am clicking on updateFlag but instead of one service it is calling both.

I am trying to use event.stoppropagation()

```
<a class="list" (click)="getMailItem(id)">
<div>
<div (click)="updateFlag(email)"><span class="material-icons>flag</span></div></div>
</a>
async updateFlag(email){
try{
const result = await this.service.getFlaggedMail(email).toPromise()
}
catch(err){
}
```

Comment: Hey Asha, I notice that there's a missing " (Quotation mark) after the "UpdateFlag(email)" part, I was going to edit it out, but I thought that it could be the source of the problem. Could you check if that error is in the actual code as well?

Comment: Thanks @Miguel Vieira . I have edited that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<div (click)="updateFlag(email, $event)"><span class="material-icons>flag</span></div></div>

async updateFlag(email, event){
    try{
       event.stopPropagation();
       const result = await this.service.getFlaggedMail(email).toPromise()
    }
    catch(err){}
 }
```

Essentially, you pass the click event through to the method and stop the event propagating there.

Comment: Glad I could help.